# Decomposition of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

If decomposing the following PDE:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\,x} \left[\dfrac{\lambda}{T}  \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial\,x}\right]$

to

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\,x} \left[\dfrac{\lambda}{T}  \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial\,x}\right]  \:\rightarrow\:  \left[\dfrac{1}{T}\dfrac{\partial \lambda}{\partial\,x} - \dfrac{\lambda}{T^2}\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial\,x}\right]\dfrac{\partial^{\,2} \rho}{\partial x^{\,2}}  $

is true, could you please give me a clue of decomposing $\dfrac{\partial^{\,2} \rho}{\partial x^{\,2}}$ such that every term has only one variable as a partial derivative.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The "decomposing" you mention is simply the application of the product & chain rule of differentiation. Since $\rho$ is not a composed function nor a product, there is nothing more to do.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks, no wonder I couldn't find anything else to do :).